# CodeIgniter - Get $config['sess_expiration']

Tags: codeigniter, session

I would like to be able to read this variable when I am running my web site:

```
$config['sess_expiration']
```

Depending on which user is logged in, I would like to display the amount of time he has before the session expires.

I know we can set the session expiration, but I did find anything on how to read this value.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_cache_expire(30);
$var = session_cache_expire();
```

You can setting your session expiration using this code;